# Right REST method for logic execution

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I know this is debatable but what is the right HTTP method which just takes an input and executes the logic and returns the response.

For ex: If I have to expose a REST endpoint which takes an integer and returns some number series ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of described in RFC for HTTP protocol (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) HTTP methods can be idempotent ot not:

> Methods can also have the property of "idempotence" in that (aside from error or expiration issues) the side-effects of N > 0 identical requests is the same as for a single request. The methods GET, HEAD, PUT and DELETE share this property. Also, the methods OPTIONS and TRACE SHOULD NOT have side effects, and so are inherently idempotent.

So if your logic changes state of the system noticeably - you better use non-idempotent method - `POST`. If all changes in the system by calling service method is only record to log file - use safe HTTP method, for instance `GET`.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was thinking too. It makes sense to choose idempotent method since the endpoint is not changing any state, however just executing an action based on input and returning the response.

Answer (score 0):

For me since you are not creating /altering /removing any ressources it should be GET, but i will like to ear about other opinion on the poin.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about doesn't really sound like REST. This sounds more like an RPC call. `POST` is usually the right http method for 'anything that doesn't fit well in another method', and is commonly used for RPC calls.